# Como comparar 3 horas diferentes en un between

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tardes compañeros.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, tengo 2 campos en una tabla, hora_inicio y hora_fin.

Necesito saber, si una hora que recibo como parametro en una función, se encuentra disponible en el rango de hora_inicio y hora_fin.

Normalmente resolveria esto facilmente usando un between, el problema surge cuando el valor que debo de comparar, no hace parte de la tabla, y lo explico en la siguiente sintaxis:

La estructura de la tabla es la siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Select * From Tabla Where $parametro Between hora_inicio AND hora_fin;
```

Como se puede observar, el campo a comparar, en este caso el valor $parametro, no hace parte de la tabla, si no que solo es valor que recibo como parametro en mi funcion.

Y aca es donde me gustaria saber que alternativas o posibles soluciones tengo, adicionalmente, quiero recalcar que los campos hora_inicio y hora_fin son de tipo TIME.

Comment: Qué es fecha_inicio, qué es fecha_fin y cuál es la salida esperada de la consulta? Ve a [edit] la pregunta y lo explicas mejor, porfa.

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo, una disculpa, habia escrito mal el nombre de los campos tambien.

Comment: Dale, gracias por tomarte el tiempo. La cosa es que, si no usas el where para restringir el conjunto de salida (no usas una expresión lógica contra columnas de la tabla), le estás diciendo WHERE true (trae todo en la tabla) o WHERE false (ni siquiera hablemos). De nuevo, cuál es el resultado que esperas al comparar esos valores? Si necesitas usar datos de ejemplo, inténtalo...

Comment: @Alfabravo Agregue una foto con la estructura de la tabla, en si, lo que necesito es que me retorne todos los registros, en donde el usuario da una hora especifica, y esta hora, debe de estar en el rango de horas entre hora_inicio y hora_fin.

Comment: No llego a ver dónde está la dificultad, la comparación para saber si una hora está dentro de un rango es exactamente como lo estás indicando en el código sql que compartiste.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho El problema esta en que $parametro, es solo un valor que recibo como parametro en una funcion y no hace parte de la tabla, por lo cual, va a generar un error.

Comment: Justamente esa es la idea de lo parámetros, que sean usados como parte de las consultas ¿Por que piensas que te va a dar error? ¿Qué errror piensas que te podría dar? Eventualmente habría que ver como estás invocando la sentencia SQL desde el lenguaje que uses, pero no es un problema de SQL en todo caso.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Esta seria la consulta Select * From Tabla Where $parametro Between hora_inicio AND hora_fin; el problema es que después del where, debería de ir un campo de la tabla y no el $parametro, por tal motivo MYSQL generara un error, donde indica que el campo "13:30:00" que equivale al valor del $parametro, no existe.

Comment: Te sugeriría que encierres el valor del parámetro entre comillas simples: `.. where '2022-08-24 08:47:00'` pero, ejecutar de esta manera la sentencia sql, sin "bindear" las variables es una mala práctica e insegura. El error que estás mostrando me hace pensar que estás construyendo mal la llamada al SQL, no sé que lenguaje estás usando, te sugiero que agregues el código de la construcción y llamada a SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tengo la sensación de que lo que te está pasando es que no te fías mucho de lo que puedas recibir en `$parametro`. Ya que estás en PHP, puedes utilizar este código para asegurarte de que al SQL le proporcionas una hora y no cualquier otra cosa:

```
$parametro = date('H:i:s',strtotime($parametro));
```

El `BETWEEN` es equivalente a:

```
WHERE a BETWEEN b AND c;

WHERE b<=a AND a<=c;
```

Por lo que sí que estarías comparando `a` con los campos `b` y `c`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta David, sin embargo es un echo que el campo que estoy recibiendo es un time, el problema en si, viene que después del where, se debe mencionar el campo de la tabla que deseas comparar, sin embargo en mi caso, necesito comparar ese $parametro de tipo time que recibo, con los 2 campos de la tabla hora_inicio y hora_fin

Comment: Acabo de ampliar la respuesta, confírmame si es a lo que te referías :)